# How flavoursome is Roast Buffalo?

Tags: meat

We're considering roasting a Buffalo Rib Roast for a bunch of friends but have no idea how it will turn out. How does this meat compare (assuming it's cooked medium rare) to something like a Beef Sirloin Roast? Are there other meats that are particularly similar? Will it be succulent or dry out? How does the flavor profile compare with beef? Is it particularly gamey?

Comment: I'm tempted to write "Very", but know I would be hugely downvoted. Bison is a delicious red meat. It is not too gamey, and is quite lean and healthy as far as red meats go. I love it. I would go with bison over beef any day if I had the option to do so.

Comment: This is subjective - VTC.

Comment: Whatever it is, don't serve your friends food you haven't tried yourself before (including a new recipe for an established dish).

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: If rephrased as "what is the flavor and texture of buffalo, in particular compared to beef?" without words like "succulent" or "flavorsome", I think it's a completely valid question. It's already managed to produce two answers with some good objective information.

Comment: Then it needs rephrasing...

Comment: Disagree with @rumtscho. Trying something new with friends is way more fun that by yourself.

Comment: I'll admit, my friends are often guinea pigs for new dishes for me.

Answer (score 2):

I can't help but think this will be a winner. Buffalo tastes very similar to beef, but has a richer flavor, almost (but not exactly) like what you get when you dry age a steak.

Buffalo is much leaner, obviously, but I honestly don't think that will make much of a difference in a rib roast. If it were a Chuck or brisket cut, I might feel differently, but a rib roast should not give you any problems, given that you are only roasting it for 1.5-2 hours.

Take it for what it's worth (not much, because it's a totally different cut of meat) -- I had a braised buffalo short rib at Ted's Montana Grill, and it was surprisingly excellent. It was very tender, but was so much more flavorful than a beef short rib.

Answer (score 1):

In general, buffalo meat tends to be leaner than beef. The lack of fat can make buffalo taste drier than beef. If you're using a slower cooking method, like roasting, you'll want to pay careful attention to the amount of fat to make sure the meat doesn't dry out.